# RequestDispatcher forward between Tomcat instances

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have a scenario where I have single entry point Servlet and further Servlets that requests are forwarded to that undertake heavy processing.

I am looking at options to distribute this load and I would like to know if it is possible using Tomcat or another platform to forward requests between Servlets sitting on different servers using a cluster type configuration or similar.

I have found some documentation on clustering Servlets and Tomcat but none indicate if Servlet request forwarding is possible from what I can see.

http://java.sun.com/blueprints/guidelines/designing_enterprise_applications_2e/web-tier/web-tier5.html

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/cluster-howto.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could distribute it over webapps in a clustered Tomcat environment and add `crossContext="true"` to the `<Context>` element of the webapps in question. Here's an extract of [Tomcat's Context Configuration Reference](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html):

> `crossContext`
>
> Set to `true` if you want calls within this application to `ServletContext.getContext()` to successfully return a request dispatcher for other web applications running on this virtual host. Set to `false` (the default) in security conscious environments, to make `getContext()` always return `null`.

This way you can obtain the desired `RequestDispatcher` as follows:

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getContext(name).getRequestDispatcher(path);
```